# Android app force closing,SQLite Database Stuff

Tags: javascript, android, sql, sqlite

I'm working on my project app to learn more about the Android app development process. I'm following an online tutorial, but I seem to be hitting an error with the SQLite Database stuff. It compiles fine, but it force closes as soon as it is run. Here is the logcat output:

```js
05-04 12:33:21.980 4403-4403/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-04 12:33:22.177 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
05-04 12:33:22.187 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
05-04 12:33:22.594 4403-4410/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/art: Debugger is active
05-04 12:33:22.792 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: Debugger has connected
05-04 12:33:22.792 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:23.014 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:23.216 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:23.417 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:23.617 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:23.817 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:24.018 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:24.218 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:24.418 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:24.619 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 12:33:24.820 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/System.out: debugger has settled (1454)
05-04 12:33:25.079 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-04 12:33:25.130 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
05-04 12:33:25.130 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
05-04 12:33:25.188 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f06005a (t=5 e=90) (error -75)
05-04 12:33:25.188 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-04 12:33:25.190 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9, PID: 4403
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class Button
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9:drawable/icontambah" (7f06005a)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06005a a=-1 r=0x7f06005a}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:837)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
05-04 12:33:39.356 4403-4403/com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4403 SIG: 9
```

Here is my code :

DbConfig.Java

```js
package com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DbConfig extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "biodatamahasiswa.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public DbConfig (Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "create table biodata (no integer primary key,nama text null,tgl text null,jk text null,alamat text null)";
        Log.d("Data","OnCreate: "+sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO biodata (no,nama,tgl,jk,alamat) VALUES ('1','Aulia Azmi','1998-07-14','Laki-Laki','Petamburan','Jakarta')";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {

    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java :

```js
package com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity<item> extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] daftar;
    ListView Listview01;
    Menu menu;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    DbConfig dbcenter;
    public static MainActivity ma;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                Intent inte = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BuatBiodataActivity.class);
                startActivity(inte);

            }
        });

        ma = this;
        dbcenter = new DbConfig(this);
        RefreshList();
    }

    public void RefreshList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbcenter.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM BIODATA",null);
        daftar = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int cc = 0;cc<cursor.getCount();cc++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(cc);
            daftar[cc] = cursor.getString(1).toString();
        }
        Listview01 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Listview01.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,daftar));
        Listview01.setSelected(true);
        Listview01.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                final String selection = daftar[arg2];
                final CharSequence[] dialogitem = {"Lihat Biodata","Update Biodata","Hapus Biodata"};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Pilihan");
                builder.setItems(dialogitem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        switch (item) {
                            case 0:
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LihatBiodataActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("nama",selection);
                                startActivity(i);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UpdateBiodataActivity.class);
                                in.putExtra("nama",selection);
                                startActivity(in);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                SQLiteDatabase db = dbcenter.getWritableDatabase();
                                db.execSQL("delete from biodata where nama='"+selection+"'");
                                RefreshList();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();
                }

            });
        ((ArrayAdapter) Listview01.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
```

BuatBiodataActivity.Java

```js
package com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class BuatBiodataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected Cursor cursor;
    DbConfig dbHelper;
    Button ton1,ton2;
    EditText text1,text2,text3,text4,text5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buat_biodata);

        dbHelper = new DbConfig(this);
        text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        text4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        text5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        ton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                db.execSQL("insert into biodata(no,nama,tgl,jk,alamat)values('"+
                        text1.getText().toString()+"','"+
                        text2.getText().toString()+"','"+
                        text3.getText().toString()+"','"+
                        text4.getText().toString()+"','"+
                        text5.getText().toString()+"')");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                finish();
            }
        });
        ton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LihatBiodataActivity.Java

```js
package com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LihatBiodataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected Cursor cursor;
    DbConfig dbHelper;
    Button ton2;
    TextView text1,text2,text3,text4,text5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lihat_biodata);

        dbHelper = new DbConfig(this);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM biodata WHERE nama='"+getIntent().getStringExtra("nama")
                +"'",null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(0);
            text1.setText(cursor.getString(0).toString());
            text2.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
            text3.setText(cursor.getString(2).toString());
            text4.setText(cursor.getString(3).toString());
            text5.setText(cursor.getString(4).toString());
        }
        ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

UpdateBiodataActivity.Java

```js
package com.example.a1713500104_crudsqlite_9;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class UpdateBiodataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected Cursor cursor;
    DbConfig dbHelper;
    Button ton1, ton2;
    EditText text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_biodata);

        dbHelper = new DbConfig(this);
        text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        text4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        text5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM biodata WHERE nama='" + getIntent().getStringExtra("nama") +
                "'", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.moveToPosition(0);
            text1.setText(cursor.getString(0).toString());
            text2.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
            text3.setText(cursor.getString(2).toString());
            text4.setText(cursor.getString(3).toString());
            text5.setText(cursor.getString(4).toString());
        }
        ton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                db.execSQL("update biodata set nama='" +
                        text2.getText().toString() + "',tgl='" +
                        text3.getText().toString() + "',jk='" +
                        text4.getText().toString() + "',alamat='" +
                        text5.getText().toString() + "'where no='" +
                        text1.getText().toString() + "'");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                finish();
            }
        });
        ton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

If someone could help me find the error in the code and suggest a fix, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thank you very much in advance for helping a noob like me :)

Comment: This questions will probably get closed soon. Remember, that this site is not a debugging service. Also, have a look at how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to present a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)/.

Comment: You should read the logcat before starting conclusions. I don't think your logcat suggests any problem with the database. The problem altars to be with UI layout inflation. You have to post the layout XML of the project to get more help.

Comment: In `activity_main`, you have a `<Button>` (or possibly an `<AppCompatButton>`) that has `@drawable/icontambah` set on it for some attribute. That `icontambah` is apparently not available for the Android version that you're testing on. The most common issue is having the drawable in the `v24` folder only, and testing on an earlier version. If you're going to use that drawable unconditionally, then an `icontambah` needs to be available in every version. If it's not a vector drawable, you can probably just move it to the base `drawable/` folder. If it is, other adjustments might need to be made.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your button as a class field in `MainActivity.Java`.

```
String[] daftar;
ListView Listview01;
Menu menu;
protected Cursor cursor;
DbConfig dbcenter;
public static MainActivity ma;
Button btn; // <------
```

And in the method `onCreate`, assign an object to it.

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Comment: This is only one possible solution to the problem. Write `xml` files. And then, I may be more likely to be able to give you the right solution.